# Cause of possible PC corruption

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

Been trying to fix my Mum's computer (it's now currently doing a full factory restore). I'm trying to work out the cause of the problem.

The mouse stopped working so she rebooted the computer and then it crapped itself. It was saying something like autocheck not found and then was BSOD'ing with a 0x000021a error. It was impossible to get windows own recovery menu up as it was BSOD'ing before you got the chance

She's rebooted it in the past when the mouse has stopped working with no problems

From googling it looks like that's caused by something in the user-mode subsystem crapping itself.

It only had that major windows update (the last big six-monthly update) a couple of days ago, which IMHO is just a little too much of a coincidence.

Would something about that major update likely be the cause???

Comment: Unless you can provide the WinDiag results on the dmp file for the BSOD you receive we cannot determine the cause of the problems you describe.  It certainly will be difficult to verify if anything since you reinstalling Windows.  Even if an update was the cause it will be impossible to verify that fact since you have already started the process of reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately until windows is reinstalled there's no way to access the dump file as windows BSODs before you even get the chance to select safe mode, system restore, etc

Comment: If you reinstall Windows the file will be deleted.  You would have had to mount the volume in another computer obviously to get the file.  However, since you already reinstalled Windows, it’s to late for that.

Comment: @Ramhound It probbaly wouldn't be viable to get the HDD out. Her last PC to get the HDD out you had to physically destroy the case due to where it HDD cage was located

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows Updates do not corrupt the operating system (I estimate this to be true more than 95% of the time).  Microsoft tests machine / driver combinations and does not offer feature updates (6 month updates) until the machine is ready for it.

Please review:

https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc000021a/

> The 0xC000021A error is a Blue Screen of Death or BSoD error (related:
> Blue Screen of Death guide) that occurs when a Windows user-mode
> subsystem is compromised.

Likely, I think, something happened (such as possible malware downloaded when visiting some websites).

Also quite possible for some legacy software (not kept up to date) may cause this. ** You certainly should update all Drivers using the Vendor Driver update app.

Finally, download Vendor Hardware diagnostics and test the hardware thoroughly - especially memory.